# Remove all HTML tags from column present Dataset in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Here is query regarding the text formatting inside the column as its value.

## The scenario is

I have one Power BI data set with HTML tags present in it.
Now I would like to remove all the HTML tags from the column value and keep only the plain text.

Below is the example for better understanding - 
   Column1 = "

```
<ul style="margin-top:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0.375in;unicode-bidi:embed;direction:ltr;"></ul></ul><p>
Number of products sold</p><p>2000</p><p>This is for the month of January</p>
```

"

Now The required formatted text should be -

> Number of products sold  2000  This is for the month of January

---

I heard that we can do it with Power Query but I don't have much knowledge regarding the same, can someone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
= Web.Page("your html text")
```

Make sure you escape " characters as ""

Comment: I dont understand how this is meant to work.  I Add a Custom Column and use that Web.Page function (passing it my Text field containing HTML), but the result is a table-type column.  Where's the cleaned text?

Comment: Hi Mike, from what I remember, I didn't really answered to the question of "how to clean the text", but I gave him something that'll make him not need to clean the text, just get the data he needs :)

Answer (score 1):

Html.Table([Your Column Name Here], {{"text",":root"}}){0}[text]